# Wordpress Add Custom CSS to Stylesheet

Tags: themes, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a theme option section for an WP theme using the code provided at http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API ( Example Theme Customization Class )

I added some sections, i modified some CSS elements and everything working fine in Theme Customizer. The problem is when I press Save and Publish the changes are wrote directly to the header of the WP Theme and I dont like it.

Is there any way to modify that script in order to save to the Stylesheet file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It saves to `wp_head` on line 149. You could comment that line out and try something like this:

```
$old = fopen(get_template_directory().'/style.css', a);
fwrite($old, array( 'MyTheme_Customize' , 'header_output' ));
fclose($old);
```